# Create expandable UITableView and normal UITableviewCell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have dictionary structure, which is as follows

```
{
    data =     {
        "parent_category_list" =         (
                        {
                "cat_master_id" = 127;
                "cat_name" = Accessories;
                "cul_name" = en;
                "culture_category_id" = 127;
                "local_id" = 283;
                "parent_id" = 0;
                "pms_id" = 127;
                slug = "accessories-1";
            },
                        {
                "cat_master_id" = 323;
                "cat_name" = "Acrylic Products";
                "cul_name" = en;
                "culture_category_id" = 323;
                "local_id" = 247;
                "parent_id" = 0;
                "pms_id" = 323;
                slug = "acrylic-products-1";
            },{
                "cat_master_id" = 252;
                "cat_name" = Coolers;
                child =                 (
                                        {
                        "cat_master_id" = 1200;
                        "cat_name" = "Drink Ware";
                        "cul_name" = en;
                        "culture_category_id" = 2031;
                        "local_id" = 284;
                        "parent_id" = 250;
                        "pms_id" = 1200;
                        slug = "drink-ware-1";
                    }
                );
}
```

I want to arrange the above dictionary in `UITableView` in such a way that, if dictionary has sub-category **i.e**. child dictionary then cell should be expandable or if in case of no sub-category then that should be normal cell. Which should be clickable.
How can I set this?

Comment: You should at least attempt to solve the problem and explain the steps you took so we can guide you towards a solution. Right now you expect the community to do your homework for you:)

Comment: I  have done something like you are trying to do and I have done it well.

Comment: I will recommend you to do it using Model classes, and parent class have array of child classes

Answer (score 0):

Here i am taking all your dictionaries into an array named "arr"

```
arr=[data objectForKey:@"parent_category_list"];
```

And implemented the UITableView delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath based on the dictionary data. If the dictionary has subcategory i am printing a log saying "cell is not clickable". For normal dictionary printing log saying "cell is clickable".

Check the below code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dictSubCat=[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"child"];

    if ([dictSubCat isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || dictSubCat==nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"cell is clickable");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"cell is not clickable");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ....

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
 if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
  // set initial height for row 
    self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
    [tableView endUpdates];

}
else
{
 self.expandedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row     inSection:indexPath.section];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath;

     if ([[[[data objectForKey:@"parent_category_list"]   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"child"] count]==0)
        {
           // set here expanded height for row 
         // clickable....
        }

        else{
            // no clickable...
        }


    }

   else
   {
   self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
   }

 [tableView endUpdates];
}
}
```